# Generalized Permutations where $n_{1} + n_{2} + n_{3} \neq N$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am working with generalized permutations with problems such as the following:

Compute $P(10;4,4,2)$: **Answer by formula: $\dfrac{10!}{(4!\, 4! \,2!)}$**

A similar problem asks to Compute $P(17;4,3,2)$. It is my understanding that N ($17$ in this case) is supposed to equal the sum of $n_{1}$, $n_{2}$, and $n_{3}$ ($4$, $3$, and $2$ respectively).

Would it be wrong to compute the answer in the same way? $\dfrac{17!}{(4!\,3!\,2!)}$ ?

Comment: If you are supposed to solve P(17;4,3,2) with 4+3+2 = 17 that'd be impossible for obvious reasons.  This question simply does not make any sense.  What are you *really* being asked to do?

Comment: How is $P(N; n_1, n_2, n_3)$ defined?

Comment: @fleablood The only problem description is "Compute P(17;4,3,2)". I have found the answer however. It seems P(17;4,3,2) is equivalent to P(17,9)/(4!*3!*2!), essentially allowing for us to insert the missing sum into the divisor in order to get 17!/(4!*3!*2!*8!).

Answer (score 1):

You have already got the answer, but I'd like to explain a point, and an approach.

Although I haven't encountered it before, P(10;4,4,2) is just the multinomial coefficient $\binom{10}{4,4,2}$

Now $\binom{10}{4,4,2} = \binom{10}{4}\binom64\binom22 = \frac{10!}{4!4!2!},$  and when expanded as a product of binomial coefficients,
**the last term e.g. $\binom22$ here, always evaluates to $1$**

So sometimes, the last term in the lower index is omitted, e.g. asked how many ways there are to get four $6's$ and four $1's$ in $10$ throws, we might abbreviate it to $\binom{10}{4,4}$

For your particular question, using your notation,
I would thus prefer to write the answer as $P(17;4,3,2,8)$